No authentication box appears when authenticating Google Earth Engine (GEE) Python in VS code notebook
I try to authenticate the GEE, the kernel keeps running, but authenticating box does not show to paste the authentication code in (picture below, but no authentication box showed). Anyone has similar experience?


You should add the authentication code to the box appearing on top of VSCode. This is the same box displayed under "the authorization workflow will generate a code which you should paste in the box below" in Jupyter.

